# Do non-product metrics on product spaces still satisfy a "sectional inequality"?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, metric-spaces

> Let $X, Y$ be connected manifolds and $g$ a Riemannian metric on $X\times Y$ inducing a metric $d$. Is it true that for $x_1,x_2\in X, y_1,y_2\in Y$ one has:
>
> $$\inf_{x\in X}d[(x,y_1),(x,y_2)]≤d[(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)].$$

Some additional (not very useful) remarks:

The conditions of $X,Y$ being manifolds and $d$ coming from a Riemannian metric are likely overkill. If the statement is true it is likely already true for much less stringent conditions, I would guess something like path connected + locally path connected + locally compact is enough.

For product metrics of the form $d[(x_1,y_2), (x_2,y_2)] = d_X(x_1,x_2)+ d_Y(y_1,y_2)$ or $d=\max(d_X, d_Y)$ the statement is trivial.

Comment: How is $d$ induced by $g$?

Comment: The distance between two points is the infimum of the length of all smooth paths connecting them. The length of a path may be defined as $L(\gamma)=\int \|\dot\gamma(t)\|\,dt$.

Comment: Thank you......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a counterexample pull back the standard Riemannian metric under the diffeomorphism $\phi: \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2, (x_1,x_2)\mapsto (x_1,4 x_1^2+x_2)$. The induced metric $d$ is then given by $d(x,y)=d_2(\phi(x),\phi(y))$ where $d_2$ is the euclidean metric. Now consider the points $(0,0)$, $(\frac 1 2,-1)$.

Comment: That works! (I edited your notation a bit so that the points and the components don't get mixed up.)